# Broken Nested Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I have mysql hidden nested table. When the yellow arrow click, the nested table show/hide. The problem is my table row got broken.

[image]

Just like the image above, the other table row had been broken. What is the problem with this?

```
    <?php
        echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>';
            echo'<tbody>';
        $i=1;   
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'<tr>
                <td align="center" id="none">';
                if (empty($row['qtysum'])){
                echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></td>';
                } else {
                echo '<a onclick="toggleTable(this);" data-counter="'.$rowid.'" href="#"><img src="images/arrow_right.png" border="0" width="15" height="15" title="Show List of '.$row["item_name"].'"></a></td>';
                }
                echo'<td>'.$i++.'</td>
                </tr>';

echo'<tr>';
        echo'<table id="loginTable'.$rowid.'" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>';
            echo'<tbody>';
        $i=1;   
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$i++.'</td>
            </tr>';
           }
    echo "</tbody></table></tr>";
           }
          }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    ?>
```

Here's my script of show/hide table.

```
<script>
function toggleTable(link) {
     var elem=document.getElementById("loginTable" + link.getAttribute('data-counter'));
     var hide = elem.style.display =="none";
     if (hide) {
        elem.style.display="table";
     } else {
        elem.style.display="none";
     }
     return false;
 }
</script>
```

If has `<tr><td> </td></tr>`

Comment: View your page source and post the HTML markup which has been constructed by the PHP code and rendered differently than you expect. That'll make it easier for us and maybe you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there were no parent `td` opened before the child table was created, and the closing tags also was missing.

The parts where changes was made is commented using `<!-- -->`

```
    <?php
        echo'<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>';
            echo'<tbody>';
        $i=1;   
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'<tr>
                <td align="center" id="none">';
                if (empty($row['qtysum'])){
                echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></td>';
                } else {
                echo '<a onclick="toggleTable(this);" data-counter="'.$rowid.'" href="#"><img src="images/arrow_right.png" border="0" width="15" height="15" title="Show List of '.$row["item_name"].'"></a></td>';
                }
                echo'<td>'.$i++.'</td>
                </tr>';

echo'<tr><td>'; <!-- there was no td opened here -->
        echo'<table id="loginTable'.$rowid.'" border="1" align="center" style="display:none">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>';
            echo'<tbody>';
        $i=1;   
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$i++.'</td>
            </tr>';
           }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    <!-- opened tr,td are closed here -->
        echo "</td></tr>"
           }
          }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I updated my question with an image of results of your answer.